# Convert internal table to csv dump

Tags: abap

I use the function module `SAP_CONVERT_TO_CSV_FORMAT` but I have the following runtime error `UC_OBJECTS_NOT_CHARLIKE`.

The field that causes the error is a type I.

What should I do avoid the short dump?

```
CALL FUNCTION 'SAP_CONVERT_TO_CSV_FORMAT'
    EXPORTING
      i_field_seperator    = ';'
      i_line_header        = 'X'
    TABLES
      i_tab_sap_data       = p_csv1
    CHANGING
      i_tab_converted_data = gt_row
    EXCEPTIONS
      conversion_failed    = 1
      OTHERS               = 2.
```

Comment: `SAP_CONVERT_TO_CSV_FORMAT` will convert dates and cash values just fine, but not integers, which your field apparently is. You will need to cast it to a charlike value beforehand.

Comment: Thank's. After changing the type to char the funziotn module works correctly.